# Not able to login the page with okta using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, okta-api

i have created the simple login page using AngularJS integrate with [**okta api**](https://dev-498575.oktapreview.com/api/v1/authn) this POST API I am passing the parameters like:

> 1) Username
>
> 2) password
>
> 3) option:multiOptionalFactorEnroll:true
>
> warnBeforePasswordExpired:true

it's throwing the `500 internal server error`, can you help me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a CORS issue please add `"Allow-access-control-origin": "*"` in **headers** while doing a **post request** and also [Check this link and allow your website to access the same](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors)

Answer (score 0):

Cross Origin issues can be bypassed by disabling chrome web security (provided you are testing in chrome browser):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```

But, please be advised this approach will work only in your local machine and for server you will need to use the approach as mentioned by @Neha Tawar